# How to get SD card size programmatically in _EMULATOR_ in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sdcard, android-virtual-device

This works perfectly well on a real gadget connected via an USB cord while in debugging mode:

```
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
    long bytesTotal = (long) stat.getBlockSize() * (long) stat.getBlockCount();
    long bytesAvail = (long) stat.getBlockSize() * (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks();
```

If, however, I try to run it with an AVD, all I get is 0 bytes. **Tools | Android | AVD Manager | Your Virtual Devices | View Details** gave me this:

1. Name: Nexus_5_API_21_x86
2. CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)
3. Path: C:\Users\Owner.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd
4. Target: Google APIs (API level 21)
5. Skin: nexus_5
6. SD Card: 200M
7. Snapshot: no
8. hw.dPad: no
9. runtime.network.speed: full
10. hw.accelerometer: yes
11. hw.device.name: Nexus 5
12. vm.heapSize: 64
13. skin.dynamic: no
14. hw.device.manufacturer: Google
15. hw.gps: yes
16. hw.audioInput: yes
17. tag.id: google_apis
18. hw.camera.back: emulated
19. hw.mainKeys: no
20. AvdId: Nexus_5_API_21_x86
21. hw.camera.front: emulated
22. hw.lcd.density: 480
23. runtime.scalefactor: auto
24. avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5 API 21 x86
25. snapshot.present: no
26. hw.device.hash2: MD5:2fa0e16c8cceb7d385183284107c0c88
27. hw.ramSize: 1536
28. hw.trackBall: no
29. hw.battery: yes
30. hw.sdCard: no
31. tag.display: Google APIs
32. runtime.network.latency: none
33. hw.keyboard: no
34. hw.sensors.proximity: yes
35. disk.dataPartition.size: 200M
36. hw.sensors.orientation: yes
37. avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
38. hw.gpu.enabled: yes

Line 6 says I've got a 200MB SD card; Line 30 looks rather suspicious, though. Does it relate to HAXM virtualization, by any chance? And the big question: how to get the SD card/external storage size at run-time? I'd really appreciate any suggestion 'cause I'm sort of at loss right now... :\

---

**EDIT:**
Alright, now I'll be answering my own question.
The issue resolved itself after re-building AVD from scratch. Now I have all my MBs.
Funny. Must be a glitch or smth...
And no, there's no relation to HAXM whatsoever. I undestood that after watching a Lynda.com video tutorial by David Gassner (he used HAXM, too, and had no problems.)

Comment: When answering your own question it's usually a good idea to answer your own question, using the "Answer your own question" button below, so others see your question is answered.

Comment: @JonasCz: Got it. TNX.